# How do I keep the same row selected in a datagridview after refreshing the dataset?

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview, timer, dataset

This code is called from a timer tick event so that the dataviewgrid refreshes at frequent intervals.

From other answers I found on SO I would expect this code to reset the selected row to the row that was selected before this code runs, refreshing my dataset.

Only the variable CurrentSelectedRow is a public variable, all others are local.

```
sql = "select top 10 batch, TrussName, PieceName from FitaPieces order by SawTime desc "

    myDataset = SelectFromDB(sql)

    MyPreviouslyCutPieces.ClearAll()

    Me.dgvPreviouslyCut.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect

    If Not IsNothing(Me.dgvPreviouslyCut.CurrentRow) Then
        Debug.Print(Now.ToString & "...Current Row = " & Me.dgvPreviouslyCut.CurrentRow.ToString)
        CurrentSelectedRow = Me.dgvPreviouslyCut.CurrentRow.Index
    Else
        Debug.Print(Now.ToString & "...Current Row = -1")
        CurrentSelectedRow = -1
    End If

    If Not myDataset Is Nothing Then
        If myDataset.Tables("CurData").Rows.Count > 0 Then

            Me.dgvPreviouslyCut.DataSource = myDataset
            Me.dgvPreviouslyCut.DataMember = "CurData"

        End If
    End If

    If CurrentSelectedRow <> -1 Then
        Me.dgvPreviouslyCut.Rows(0).Selected = False
        Me.dgvPreviouslyCut.Rows(CurrentSelectedRow).Selected = True
    End If
```

And it does..for the first tick of the timer event. On the second tick event after the user selects a row, it reverts back to the first row being selected. Even though the variable CurrentSelectedRow is a public variable, it's getting reset to zero after the first tick event. Then the selected row switches back to the first row in the grid.  The first row is auto selected when you refresh a grid's datasource, but I'm setting it's selected status to false after the refresh.

How is the dataviewgrid's selected row getting reset to the first row?

Comment: Just use a variable to keep track of what row is highlighted and then when the DataGrid is refreshed, make sure that row get highlighted again. See answer below.

Comment: when you say same row selected does it mean same data/record or the selected row only?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you can't seem to get the DataGridView to work. Try a different control until you do get the problem solved. I have personally used a listbox to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Not the best way to help someone!

Comment: Please consider your responses before giving an "answer"

Answer (score 2):

Grab the current index and store it in a variable called "go_back_to_index"

```
Dim go_back_to_index as integer
```

when the user clicks on the row in the grid, just save the value so you can highlight it later:

```
go_back_to_index = current_data_grid.currentRow.value
```

then when the grid is updated, just run this piece of code:

```
If go_back_to_index < current_data_grid.Rows.Count Then
      current_data_grid.Rows(go_back_to_index).Selected = True
      current_data_grid.CurrentCell = current_data_grid.Item(1, go_back_to_index)
End If
```

Remember to make sure you set up your datagrid so the whole row is highlighted when a cell is clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is happening is because you're changing the `DataSource` of the grid in every cycle.

The best way (but the hardest way) to solve this  is to run the DataGridView in [VirtualMode](https://www.google.no/search?q=datagridview%20virtual%20mode&oq=datagridview%20virt&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.3917j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8).

If not, one should set the data source *only once*. And when you need to update the table, merge the table bound to the grid with the new table.

```
DirectCast(Me.dgvPreviouslyCut.DataSource, DataTable).Merge(myDataset.Tables("CurData"))
```